# How to assign a canvas to multiple widgets in Kivy

Tags: python, canvas, kivy

I would like to give all of the widgets on the screen a white canvas. I know how to create the intended canvas in `KV` but in this case I must use Python code.

In my code, I tried `self.cavas.add(...)` and in the code below, I use `with self.canvas:`. Both attempts resulted in a canvas being drawn in the corner of the screen, rather than inside of the widgets.

How do I put a canvas to be inside of every widget using Python code?

**Code**:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Rectangle
from kivy.lang import Builder
from random import random
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock

class LittleButtons(Button):

    dur = 2

    def reup(self, *args):

        Animation.cancel_all(self)
        Animation(pos_hint = {'center_x': random(), 'center_y': random()}, duration = self.dur).start(self)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(LittleButtons, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pos_hint = {'center_x': random(), 'center_y': random()}
        self.size_hint = None, None
        self.width = random() * (Window.width / 20)
        self.height = self.width
        self.background_color = [0,0,0,.05]
        with self.canvas:
            Color(rgba = [1,1,1,.2])
            Rectangle(pos = self.pos, size = self.size)

        Animation(pos_hint = {'center_x': random(), 'center_y': random()}, duration = self.dur).start(self)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.reup, self.dur)

KV = Builder.load_string("""
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

Screen:
    FloatLayout:
        on_parent:
            (lambda ltext: [self.add_widget(Factory.LittleButtons(text=ltext)) for i in range (150)])('hi!')
        Button:
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,1,1,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size:self.size
""")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return KV

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the `LittleButtons` `__init__()` method, its position is still the default of (0,0), so the position of the `Rectangle` is set to (0,0). When you use `KV`, it cleverly binds the `Rectangle` position to the `LittleButtons` position when you reference `self.pos`. Unfortunately, in a `.py` file, you must provide that binding yourself. So, here is a modification of your `LittleButtons` that should handle the position changes:

```
class LittleButtons(Button):

    dur = 2

    def reup(self, *args):

        Animation.cancel_all(self)
        Animation(pos_hint = {'center_x': random(), 'center_y': random()}, duration = self.dur).start(self)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.rect = None
        super(LittleButtons, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pos_hint = {'center_x': random(), 'center_y': random()}
        self.size_hint = None, None
        self.width = random() * (Window.width / 20)
        self.height = self.width
        self.background_color = [0,0,0,.05]
        with self.canvas:
            Color(rgba = [1,1,1,.2])
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos = self.pos, size = self.size)

        Animation(pos_hint = {'center_x': random(), 'center_y': random()}, duration = self.dur).start(self)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.reup, self.dur)


    def on_pos(self, instance, pos):
        if self.rect is not None:
            self.rect.pos = pos
```

The changes are the addition of a `self.rect` attribute and a `on_pos` method.

You can add something similar if you need to handle changing `size`.